# I want to tap a button in webpage using TouchAction

Tags: appium

Below is my code is:

```
TouchAction circleTouch = new TouchAction((MobileDriver)driver);
circleTouch.tap(continuebutton);
circleTouch.perform();
```

This code is giving error for .perform() method. ( org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented)

I am currently using java_client 4.1.2 and selenium 3.0 and using AppiumDriver.

Answer (score 0):

How have you declared driver? Try it with -

```
AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
```

and see if your code works. Try the code like this -

```
TouchAction circleTouch = new TouchAction(driver);
circleTouch.tap(continuebutton).perform;
```